# Sound Converter fails to convert mp3 to m4a

Tags: mp3, m4a

It shows me an error (shown below) when I try to convert from mp3 to GNOME Audio File (.m4a)

[image]

Any tips on how I can fix this? Urgent help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

from https://answers.launchpad.net/soundconverter/+question/145978

*"The codec you need is the FAAC (free advanced audio encoder) plugin for GStreamer. It's in the package gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse; you can install the package through the Synaptic Package Manager, or in a terminal with the command:

sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse

After that M4A (or AAC) should appear as an option in Sound Converter."*

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am now trying this out, although the option already appears it shall work after. :')

Comment: After doing this.. now, a new error appears: http://i.imgur.com/CRprh.png

Comment: hmm... I'm using the ppa I mentioned in the comment to the other answer. Maybe that's why it works for me.

Comment: I'm on 12.04, when I install Ubuntu it's the 12.04 one.. since I'm having trouble with my Windows license key. Are there any working ppa for 12.04 for SoundConverter? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that Gstreamer packages are updated to latest version.

Comment: How can I install such packages? I installed using the command line and fortunately I still have the latest one I downloaded from their site (the zipped ones, .tar.gz if not mistaken).

Comment: take a look at https://launchpad.net/~gstreamer-developers/+archive/ppa for your version of Ubuntu. Be warned that moving to the latest can make your system more fragile :)

Comment: I'm on the 12.04 version, that's the version I installed using wubi when I'm still on Windows... so any ppa working for my version?